# Psexec does not open the application

Tags: windows, psexec

When I run psexec from my machine to open notepad in the remote machine, I see notepad is running as a process, but nothing is there in the Application list and notepad window has not opened in the remote window.

```
c:\Users\Ask\Downloads\PSTools>psexec -h -u administrator -p force   \\135.20.230.167 notepad.e
```

xe

What might be the reason?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I gave the -i option too, but that also failed.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279044/session-id-in-psexec/28287670#28287670